# How should OSPF work over WiFi?

Tags: ospf, ieee-802.11, multicast

I've had problems running OSPF over my WiFi network, and it seems to be related to multicast.  The routers can't maintain a neighbor relationship, and when I watch the packet traffic I see one router sending multicast Hellos to 224.0.0.5 but the other OSPF speaker is not receiving them.

The OSPF speakers are all Ubuntu Linux machines (either Ubuntu 18 or 20) running Quagga.  The AP is a Verizon Fios G1100.

I'm pretty sure there's a bug somewhere, but I'm not sure where.  Since there's no true broadcast or multicast over WiFi, the AP has to relay the multicast frames.  Should it do this automatically?  Or should the OSPF speakers announce their interest in 224.0.0.5 via IGMP?

Incidentally, adding a neighbor statement to the Quagga configuration doesn't seem to help.  I resolved the problem by switching to RIP.

Comment: "_Since there's no true broadcast or multicast over WiFi_" That is not true. Multicast and broadcast on Wi-Fi can work, but it requires the slowest possible speed in order to reach distant hosts. Unfortunately, your WAP is an off-topic consumer-grade device, and your router manufacturer does not offer optional, paid support, which is required for devices here. You could always set up OSPF to use unicast and neighbor statements, but wireless can still be problematic.

Comment: @RonMaupin aren't the WiFi packets encrypted so that only the AP can decode them?

Comment: @RonMaupin, also, would you mind actually answering the question I asked before closing the question?  Should OSPF speakers announce their interest in multicast addresses via IGMP or not?

Comment: The WAP gets the broadcast or multicast and then sends it to all hosts on the LAN (really no different than an ethernet switch getting the broadcast or multicast and sending it to all interfaces) at the slowest possible speed. Some WAPs can be configured to replicate, via unicast to each host, but that can greatly slow things, too, since it needs to send a frame for each attached host, rather than one broadcast or multicast frame.

Comment: IGMP plays no part in multicasts for the Local Network Control Block of multicast. IGMP is for multicast routing, and multicast addresses in that block cannot be routed. IGMP is a protocol for a host to communicate with a multicast router.

Comment: Weird.  My packet trace shows a bunch of IGMP membership reports for various 224.0.0.x address - rip (9), ospf (5 and 6), mDNS (251)

Comment: That has to do with the off-topic implementation on you host, not the actual protocol theory. Linux often ignores the networking standards. In any case, your question is simply off-topic here. and you need to ask on the correct SE site.

Comment: Notice what RFC 5771 says, "_Addresses in the Local Network Control Block are used for protocol control traffic **that is not forwarded off link**._"

Comment: IGMP joins are **REQUIRED** for any group a node wishes to receive. It has little to do directly with multicast routing, and everything to do with proper flow of multicast to every node that wants it. (switches do filter out unregistered multicast.) How do you know if a node is multicast capable unless it has asked for at least one group?

Comment: To answer the question, yes there should be a join for the OSPF group. Yes, multicast over wifi is a problem; esp. on cheap consumer level crap. Running OSPF over WiFi is asking for trouble.

Comment: @RickyBeam, IGMP is _not_ required for `224.0.0.0/24`, as the RFC explains: "_**...based on the fact that many host systems do not send Join IP multicast addresses in this range before sending or listening to IP multicast packets. Furthermore, since the 224.0.0.X address range is defined as link-local (not to be routed), it seems unnecessary to keep the state for each address in this range. Additionally, some routers operate in the 224.0.0.X address range without issuing IGMP Joins...**_"

Comment: RFC 3376 (v3) and 2236 (v2) lists all-systems (.1) as the only special case for never being joined. [2236, p.10] *The all-systems group (address 224.0.0.1) is handled as a special case.  The host starts in Idle Member state for that group on every interface, never transitions to another state, and never sends a report for that group.* [3376, p.19] *No IGMP messages are ever sent regarding the all-systems multicast address.* (having seen the source for a few switches, if you don't join any group, or tx any multicast, the system assumes you aren't multicast capable and filters it out.)

Comment: (RFC4541 is **INFORMATIONAL** It is not a rule. 2.1.2(2) is merely a *recommendation* -- the first three words of that sentence was conveniently left off.)

Comment: @RickyBeam, the important part is that it is a recommendation based on what really happens in that "_...many host systems do not send Join IP multicast addresses in this range before sending or listening to IP multicast packets..._" and "_...some routers operate in the 224.0.0.X address range without issuing IGMP Joins..._" It is not required for multicast groups in that range.